# Tell SSH to use a graphical prompt for key passphrase

Tags: ssh

How can I force SSH to request passphrases using a graphical prompt (GTK, for example) instead of the standard one that uses the terminal?

I tried setting `SSH_ASKPASS=/usr/bin/ssh-askpass` but it seems to have no effects.

The problem is the fact the openssh documentation says

> If ssh **does not have a terminal associated with it** but DISPLAY and SSH_ASKPASS are set, it will execute the program specified by SSH_ASKPASS and open an X11 window to read the passphrase.

An ssh launched from the command line, in my case as the result of a `git push`, *will* have a terminal associated with it, so the `SSH_ASKPASS` logic seems to be ignored.

Please note that I am not referring to `ssh-add`, but to generic ssh invocations towards an hosts for which a key pair is present but protected by a passphrase.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It only took 19 years to solve this issue [OpenSSH Bug 69 - generalised-askpass](https://bugzilla.mindrot.org/show_bug.cgi?id=69).

> OpenSSH 8.4 will include a $SSH_ASKPASS_REQUIRE variable that accepts force|prefer|never options.

When I set SSH_ASKPASS_REQUIRE to prefer then `ssh-add` from the terminal will launch the ssh-askpass user interface. On my Arch Linux machine I have the following in my `.xinitrc`

```
export SSH_ASKPASS=/usr/lib/ssh/x11-ssh-askpass
export SSH_ASKPASS_REQUIRE=prefer
eval `keychain --eval --noask ~/.ssh/id_rsa`
```

And in my `~/.ssh/config` I have

```
AddKeysToAgent yes
```

So when I run e.g. `git pull` in one of my projects the very first time after a reboot, then the askpass dialog will correctly popup and ask for the password only a single time.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 43):

#### #1 - Missing package?

You're probably missing the package that contains `ssh-askpass`. Try installing it.

Fedora/CentOS/RHEL:

```
$ sudo yum install openssh-askpass
```

Debian/Ubuntu:

```
$ sudo apt-get install ssh-askpass-gnome ssh-askpass
```

#### Finding missing utilities

You can search for missing tools using these commands:

Fedora/CentOS/RHEL:

```
$ yum search ssh-askpass
Loaded plugins: langpacks, presto, refresh-packagekit
Adding en_US to language list
======================================================= Matched: ssh-askpass =======================================================
x11-ssh-askpass.x86_64 : A passphrase dialog for X and not only for OpenSSH
ksshaskpass.x86_64 : A KDE version of ssh-askpass with KWallet support
connect-proxy.x86_64 : SSH Proxy command helper
openssh-askpass.x86_64 : A passphrase dialog for OpenSSH and X
```

Debian/Ubuntu:

```
$ apt-file -l search ssh-askpass
app-install-data
cruft
git-cola
luckybackup-data
pssh
sdm-terminal
seahorse
ssh-askpass
ssh-askpass-fullscreen
ssh-askpass-gnome
```

#### #2 - Disconnected terminal?

I missed this initially but after further reading up I noticed this comment in the man page of `ssh` regarding the `SSH_ASKPASS` environment variable.

*excerpt*

```
SSH_ASKPASS    If ssh needs a passphrase, it will read the passphrase from the 
               current terminal if it was run from a terminal.  If ssh does not
               have a terminal associated with it but DISPLAY and SSH_ASKPASS 
               are set, it will execute the program specified by SSH_ASKPASS 
               and open an X11 window to read the passphrase. This is particularly
               useful when calling ssh from a .xsession or related script.  
               (Note that on some machines it may be necessary to redirect the 
               input from /dev/null to make this work.)
```

If you notice in the comment, it states that ssh "doesn't have a terminal associated" **AND** `DISPLAY` & `SSH_ASKPASS` are set. Noticing this is key. So to get `ssh` to use `SSH_ASKPASS` we need to get `ssh` to not have a terminal (aka. `STDIN` & `STDOUT`) attached to it.

One way to do this by making use of the command [`setsid`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/setsid). Don't feel bad. I never heard of this tool either. From the man page:

> setsid - run a program in a new session

So if we run `ssh` as the "program" to `setsid` we can detach `ssh` from our terminal meeting the criteria mentioned in `ssh`'s man page. The other criteria are set as follows:

```
$ echo $DISPLAY; echo $SSH_ASKPASS
:0.0
/usr/libexec/openssh/ssh-askpass
```

So if we put this all together:

```
$ setsid ssh user@remotehost
```

For example:

```
$ setsid ssh user@skinner
```

[image: ss of ask gui]

#### A solution

If you'd like to make it so that the `setsid` is "built-in" you can create an aliases like so:

```
$ alias ssh="setsid ssh"
```

Now when you `ssh` you'll get the GUI popping up asking for your password:

```
$ ssh user@skinner
```

#### References

- [reading SSH password from stdin – the openssh 5.6p1 compatible way](http://andre.frimberger.de/index.php/linux/reading-ssh-password-from-stdin-the-openssh-5-6p1-compatible-way/)

Comment: ssh-askpass gnome is installed and it works fine if launched manually.

Comment: @gioele - see updates, I think I've figured it out.

Comment: the problem of this solution is that it requires that I modify each git or rsync command to use `setsid ssh` instad of plain `ssh`.

Comment: @gioele - you asked for a method to "force" the password GUI, this provides that. You can replace commands such as `ssh` with aliases `setsid ssh` is one approach. There are other ways. The limiting factor is openssh needs no TTY attached in order to activate the ASK_SSHPASS.

Comment: I'm not missing the package and I cannot use `setsid` and then work in `ssh` from my terminal. That's just not a valid answer at all!? Plus, it was working in older versions of Ubuntu, so I'm not too sure I understand why it suddenly stopped working!

Comment: @AlexisWilke - if you have a new question I encourage you to ask. This method, as demonstrated, does work. So you may have a different set of circumstances or things may have changed with newer versions of things.

Comment: I found it! After all that reading yesterday, I finally got it. I had problems connecting because I had too many keys under `~/.ssh` so I decided to move them under `~/.ssh/other_keys`. That works in the sense that it does let you connect to servers properly, but that hides the keys from the `ssh-agent` so they do not get auto-added. Moving a key back to `~/.ssh` solves the problem, although a better solution would be to have a tool that auto-adds keys without asking for the passphrase... (like `ssh-add keyname` but silent.)

Comment: @AlexisWilke - yeah I've written about that issue before on SU: [Too many authentication failures for *username*](http://superuser.com/questions/187779/too-many-authentication-failures-for-username/294848#294848)

Comment: Interesting. I read that question/answers a while back when I ran in that problem. I now have a new question about the `ssh-add` not being able to add keys without immediately asking you for your passphrase. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/170750/is-there-a-way-to-specify-the-list-of-private-keys-to-add-to-ssh-agent Maybe someone has a solution for that one.

Comment: In the past I have come across one caveat which is not mentioned in your answer. I needed to use ssh to connect to an embedded system and I wanted to use `SSH_ASKPASS`. It turns out the embedded system used `keyboard-interactive` authentication and `SSH_ASKPASS` only works for `password`. Since the prompt displayed using `keyboard-interactive` looked exactly like the one which `password` would have used, it took me a long time before I realized why `SSH_ASKPASS` never worked for me.

Comment: The link points to the man page of `setsid(2)` while it should point to `setsid(1)`

Comment: @AlexisWilke you can create initial `ssh` session with `ControlMaster` `ssh_config` feature enabled: `setsid ssh -Nf ... host`, and then to interactively connect to the host, use: `ssh ... host` which will re-use the already authenticated `ssh` session.

Answer (score 12):

It cannot be done in OpenSSH before version 8.4: for details read the issue in the OpenSSH Bugzilla asking for this feature since 2002 and finally fixed in 2021-01: [Generalize SSH_ASKPASS](https://bugzilla.mindrot.org/show_bug.cgi?id=69).

For OpenSSH version 8.4+, see [the accepted answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/635613/14861) for a quick explanation of how to achieve this using `SSH_ASKPASS_REQUIRE`.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @cuonglm "this is not possible" is an answer. It might be wrong or misleading (I'm not saying it is), but it's still an answer.

Comment: Correct, the "it cannot be done" assertion saves us from searching the web for an answer that isn't there.

Answer (score 5):

There is a way to close the terminal for a single command, and that is using file redirection:

```
ssh-add > /dev/null < /dev/null 2>&1
```

This will run the command `ssh-add` with the terminal closed. Which is fine and dandy, except for the its complexity. But now that you know the correct command, simply make it an alias and append it to `~/.bash_aliases`:

```
alias ssh-add="/usr/bin/ssh-add > /dev/null < /dev/null 2>&1"
```

And you should be set. Simply typing `ssh-add` will now invoke the alias which will invoke the real command with all the redirection in place.

The `ssh-add` now correctly asks you the password with a dialog box... Provided that you have one of these packages installed (in Ubuntu or derivatives, they may have other names elsewhere):

- `ssh-askpass`
- `ssh-askpass-fullscreen`
- `ssh-askpass-gnome`
- `ksshaskpath`
- `kwalletcli`
- `lxqt-openssh-askpass`
- `razorqt-openssh-askpasss`

Now, what do all those things mean?

The `2>&1` means redirect file descriptor #2 (standard error) to the same place file descriptor #1 (standard output) is directed to.

The `> /dev/null` means redirect standard output to `/dev/null`, which is a special file that discards all data written to it.

The `< /dev/null` means redirect standard input to `/dev/null` (idem).

As a side note, and an off topic but related note, if you ever want to program a service in bash, you must remember what a service actually is, a process with standard input, output, and error closed that is in the background:

```
service > /dev/null < /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

Notice that the only difference is the & added at the end (plus the fact that I changed the command `ssh-add` for a theoretical `service`. Those commands will correctly put a service on the background.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer Victor. However, it does not fit my requirements. As I wrote at the end of the question, «Please note that I am not referring to ssh-add, but to generic ssh invocations towards an hosts for which a key pair is present but protected by a passphrase.».

Comment: I see.

Well, `ssh` functions the exact same way, and the same answer I gave previously still applies. Just replace every occurence of `ssh-add` with `ssh` and you are set.

Comment: There is just a tiny detail you forgot: if I close stdin/stdout for ssh, how do I give commands through ssh? ;)

Comment: This worked for `ssh-add` for me - I didn't even need to redirect stdout/stderr to get the desired behavior, which was to pop up the `ssh-askpass` program.  (That is, `ssh-add < /dev/null` was enough.)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when I installed seahorse (which provide `seahorse-ssh-askpass`) without installing the package `gnome-keyring` on ArchLinux.

Looking at the content of this package `gnome-keyring` (https://www.archlinux.org/packages/extra/i686/gnome-keyring) may help you solve your problem.

In any case, if you do not mind using seahorse, you can also install the packages `seahorse` and `gnome-keyring` (or the equivalent ones for your distribution).
If you do not use Gnome, additional steps may be required: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GNOME_Keyring.

Comment: I agree that this is an effective solution.  It doesn't force the use specifically of the ssh-askpass command, but it does provide a graphical prompt the first time a key is needed.  It provides it's own socket at $SSH_AUTH_SOCK (typiically under /run/user/NNNNN/keyring/ssh-sock) which acts like an ssh-agent.

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion, the simplest solution is to set the pinentry program of your choice using `update-alternatives`. For example for KDE this would be:

```bash
# review current default pinentry for ssh-askpass
update-alternatives --list ssh-askpass

# set
update-alternatives --force --verbose --set ssh-askpass /usr/bin/kssaskpass
```