# Force ssh to always use SSH_ASKPASS

Tags: ssh, openssh

I want to force ssh to always use the program specified by `SSH_ASKPASS`. In my case the program is just a bash script returning the passphrase.

The problem is, as the ssh documentation says:

> If ssh needs a passphrase, **it will read the passphrase from the current terminal if it was run from a terminal**.

So if I run ssh from a terminal, `SSH_ASKPASS` is ignored.

There is a similar question: 
[Tell SSH to use a graphical prompt for key passphrase](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/83986/tell-ssh-to-use-a-graphical-prompt-for-key-passphrase)

which proposes create an alias for ssh, like this

```
$ alias ssh="setsid ssh"
```

but doesn't work for me, because I don't call ssh directly, is called from git or rsync.

I also found an [open issue](https://bugzilla.mindrot.org/show_bug.cgi?id=69) in the OpenSSH Bugzilla asking for a fix, but was opened in 2002, so I don't believe is going to be implemented.

I'm thinking on probably weird solutions:

1. Make a fake ssh agent, which calls the script and returns the passphrase.
2. Create a process looking for new ssh processes and detach them from the    terminal before ssh asks for the password.

Any better sugestion?

Comment: If I read that open issue correctly, you can set `DISPLAY` to some value and then `SSH_ASKPASS` will be used.

Comment: When working in a graphical environment `DISPLAY` is already set. The question is about forcing SSH to use a GUI passphrase window. I personally would also like to use a (fullscreen) GUI way to provide passphrase but the most of all I would like to provide it *once*, i.e. I would like to talk to the SSH agent, not to the SSH client.

Answer (score 5):

A per `ssh` manual:

> If `ssh` does not have a terminal associated with it but DISPLAY and SSH_ASKPASS are set, it will execute the program specified by SSH_ASKPASS.

Therefore you need to disassociate the terminal (e.g. by adding a pipe) and make sure `DISPLAY` isn't set (if you want to use terminal for your passphrase instead).

Simple example:

```
echo foo | SSH_ASKPASS=/my/cmd DISPLAY= ssh ...
```

The same with `ssh-add`:

```
$ echo foo | SSH_ASKPASS=/my/cmd DISPLAY= ssh-add id_rsa
ssh_askpass: exec(/my/cmd): No such file or directory
```

Comment: I couldn't make it work with `echo`; however setting `DISPLAY` to whatever and using `setsid` did the trick. See [my post](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/261737/17696)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I cannot access the open issue that you have linked, but I have tried [@npostavs](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/47926/npostavs)' suggestion (set `DISPLAY` to some value) and it seems to work<sup>1</sup>.

For example:

```
# List heads in a remote git repo
DISPLAY=: setsid git ls-remote -h git@github.tik.uni-stuttgart.de:NFL/tests.git
```

Where

```
$ cat ${SSH_ASKPASS}
#!/bin/bash
echo ABCSuperPassword
```

In this example, `SSH_AGENT` is invoked by git (set `GIT_TRACE=2` for verboser output) effectively providing "*ABCSuperPassword*" as password for the private key.

#### Notes

<sup>1</sup> `DISPLAY` is often unset if login into remote terminals.