# How to find out what triggers ssh-askpass prompting for passphrase periodically

Tags: ssh, linux-mint, openssh

I recently deleted the contents of my `~/.ssh` directory and generated new keys. They new ones work fine, but **every once in a while** I am getting a gui dialog titled OpenSHH from asking for the passphrase. How can I find out what process/application is issuing the prompt. I am using Mint 17.

I've tried to find out what the parent process of sss-agent is, but it is just cinnamon-session...

Any ideas what this might be, or how to find out?

Comment: Need more information, did you generate your keys with or without pass-phrases? Also what is in your /var/log/auth.log file during those prompts? Any specific client names?

Comment: Nothing in /var/log/auth.log. It's just one key, with passphrase (or is the passphrase in addition to the password I'm asked when I git push for example?).

Comment: The git password should be different. If you generated your keys with a passphrase, it will continue to prompt you. What does this return: `grep -L ENCRYPTED ~/.ssh/id_[rd]sa`

Comment: Nothing, which means it is encrypted?

Comment: Yes, that means that you generated ssh keys with passphrases. If you open each private key and see this line: `Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED`, then you created an ssh key with a passphrase. Generate a new key like this: `ssh-keygen -b 2048`, hit enter when it asks for a phasephrase, and then enter again to confirm.

Comment: That is how I generated the key I have now. Except without the -b flag, but the man page says 2048 is the default anyway, so... The issue is not that I am being promped for the passphrase, it is that I don't know **what** is trying to use the key.

Comment: I'm sorry, I misunderstood. Is this the problem you are having?: http://blog.codonomics.com/2011/04/how-to-disable-gnome-ssh-askpass.html If so then I think you want this `unset SSH_ASKPASS`

Comment: The key thing is that I am not doing anything (that I can tell) that would require the key. I'm just using the computer, doing various things, and all of a sudden I get the prompt. I don't know what application is responsible for it.