# Is there a way to specify the list of private keys to add to ssh-agent?

Tags: ssh, password, ssh-agent

After a few hours of digging, I finally found out why my computer stopped asking me for my key(s) using gnome ssh-askpass. It was very simple, but took me forever to figure out because... well... most of the people who are having similar problems is for a completely different reason (i.e. ssh-agent not running).

In my case, I had too many keys under `~/.ssh` so what I had done was to move them all, except `id_rsa` in a sub-directory: `~/.ssh/other_keys`. That worked for the purpose of accessing some computers just using the `-i` command line option as in:

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/other_keys/topsecret domain
```

Otherwise you have to tell SSH to not test all the keys found in your `~/.ssh` directory (because when that happens, it exhausts the number of tries which is usually pretty small like 3 or 5.)

To fix this problem you could also do this:

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/topsecret -o 'IdentitiesOnly yes' domain
```

Which is a lot of typing (yes, you can also add it to your config file, but if that's just for a quick test, that's an annoyance.)

So... all of that works great for when I want to connect once here or once there, but it is painful when I want to go to one of my main servers because `ssh` now asks me for my passphrase on each access, even though my `ssh-agent` and `ssh-askpass` are properly setup.

So... what gives?

Somehow, when you start `ssh-add` it automatically adds the keys to the `ssh-agent` without asking you for your passphrases. Then once you need to use the key, it automatically starts your `ssh-askpass` (no need for a variable of that name in your environment, btw) where you can enter your passphrase and move on.

If the keys are defined in a sub-directory, however, they do not get found so they do not get added to the `ssh-agent` and when you use `ssh` it does not find them in the `ssh-agent` either and thus asks you for your passphrase directly in your console and not in a gnome popup window.

Moving keys back directly under `~/.ssh` fixes the problem, but that's not really a good solution since it breaks the `ssh -i ...` again. (I know, there is the `-o ...` option to tell ssh to use that one key only and that resolves that other problem. But I think ssh should test with the command line specified key FIRST and that would resolve both my problems. Oh well...)

So... when I run the following command:

```
ssh-add -D
```

It resets the `ssh-agent` keys by (1) deleting all the keys currently there; and (2) reinstalling all the keys found under `~/.ssh` without asking me for any passphrase (at least not at the time I run the `ssh-add` command).

Would there be a way to ask `ssh-add` (or whatever other tool) to also add the keys found in a different directory such as my `~/.ssh/other_keys` sub-directory and this without having to enter all the passphrases right then?

Comment: FYI, you can work around the issue by specifying which keys go with which sites in your `$HOME/.ssh/config` file too. This eliminates `ssh` from having to search through the keys present in the user's `$HOME/.ssh` directory.

Comment: Would it be an option to use `gpg-agent` instead?

Comment: @HaukeLaging, Well... I was more hoping for not additional setup. Especially because the default `ssh-agent` gets installed and setup automatically in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

Not a full blown answer but if you look in the man page of `ssh-agent` it has the following paragraph.

> The agent initially does not have any private keys.  Keys are added
>   using `ssh-add(1)`.  When executed without arguments, `ssh-add(1)` adds
>   the files `~/.ssh/id_rsa`, `~/.ssh/id_dsa`, `~/.ssh/id_ecdsa` and
>   `~/.ssh/identity`.  If the identity has a passphrase, `ssh-add(1)` asks
>   for the passphrase on the terminal if it has one or from a small X11
>   program if running under X11.  If neither of these is the case then
>   the authentication will fail.  It then sends the identity to the
>   agent.  Several identities can be stored in the agent; the agent can
>   automatically use any of these identities.  `ssh-add -l` displays the
>   identities currently held by the agent.

So you can see what keys are currently loaded by `ssh-agent` and it will default to loading the keys as described by that paragraph.

Comment: That's the thing, it actually adds any private key that has a corresponding .pub file in ~/.ssh without asking you for your passphrase, but it does not want to add other keys in a similar fashion.

Comment: @AlexisWilke - try importing them via seahorse instead.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the `AddKeysToAgent` option (available in recent OpenSSH versions) could be useful in this situation?

> Specifies whether keys should be automatically added to a running ssh-agent(1).  If this option is set to yes and a key is loaded from a file, the key and its passphrase are added to the agent with the default lifetime, as if by ssh-add(1).  If this option is set to ask, ssh(1) will require confirmation using the SSH_ASKPASS program before adding a key (see ssh-add(1) for details).  If this option is set to confirm, each use of the key must be confirmed, as if the -c option was specified to ssh-add(1).  If this option is set to no, no keys are added to the agent.  The argument must be yes, confirm, ask, or no (the default).