# Key passphrases and sshd -- cached authentication?

Tags: ssh, rsync, sshd, session, caching

Asking a more precise question:

It appears that I can complete an `rsync`-over-`ssh`, using a key that requires a passphrase, without entering the passphrase. For example, I can run the `rsync` from the command line:

```
rsync -qavz -e ssh -i /home/keshlam/.ssh/password_id_dsa.pub a.a password_id@192.168.122.47:/home/password_id/a.a
```

and see the `a.a` file appear on the remote machine without being prompted for the passphrase.

My best guess is that this is an ssh caching effect -- I entered the passphrase yesterday and the two machines are still trusting each other.

Does this analysis make sense? And if so what's the easiest reliable way to flush that cache for testing -- reboot?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> My best guess is that this is an ssh caching effect -- I entered the passphrase yesterday and the two machines are still trusting each other.

This is `ssh-agent` or some `gnome-keyring`, which stores your key private key encrypted so it can be used.

> what's the easiest reliable way to flush that cache for testing -- reboot?

List the keys stored in your `ssh-agent` using `ssh-add -l`. It should be listed. You can remove it using `ssh-add -d /path/to/your.key`

Comment: That worked, thanks. Unfortunately this brings me back to my other problem; the `expect` script I'm trying to use to pump the password into ssh isn't working because the password prompt is popping up as a window. Need to switch it back to command-line interaction, somehow.

Comment: I suspect the popup is also coming from ssh-agent, given that when I "deny" on that screen I get the message "Agent admitted failure to sign using the key"

Comment: @keshlam according to [this question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/83986/24712) it displays a window when you don't have an associated terminal and the environmental variable `SSH_ASKPASS` is set (and `ssh-askpass` is installed...). So (maybe) you may be able to fix this by modifying the environment and delete the variable (`unset SSH_ASKPASS`).

Comment: @bakiru: No such luck, apparently.